# Read in files and add additional unique values for shared keys

Tags: perl, csv

Sorry if the title's vague or confusing - I'm having a hard time expressing exactly what it is I'm looking to do.

I have several .csv files that contain two columns of data, in the format `"<string_id>","<string>"`. Each of these .csv files represents a different language; here's an example of three of these:

int.csv:

```
"55545","Hello.",
"55546","I'm new to perl.",
"55547","Bonus string!",
"55548","Please help.",
```

fra.csv:

```
"55545","Bonjour.",
"55546","Je suis nouveau à perl.",
"55548","S'il vous plaît aider.",
```

ita.csv:

```
"55545","Ciao.",
"55546","Sono nuovo di perl.",
"55547","Stringa di Bonus!",
"55548","Si prega di aiutare.",
```

What I'd like to do is read these files in and merge these into a single .csv, starting with int.csv and appending to the right from there. If there's an entry in int.csv that doesn't exist in one of the others, I'd like to insert an empty value so-as to keep the columns correctly aligned.

So, my desired output would be:

```
"55545","Hello.","Bonjour.","Ciao.",
"55546","I'm new to perl.","Je suis nouveau à perl.","Sono nuovo di perl.",
"55547","Bonus string!","","Stringa di Bonus!",
"55548","Please help.","S'il vous plaît aider.","Si prega di aiutare.",
```

These source .csv files are generated by a perl script I've written, so the source files can be edited if needed. My gut instinct was to parse each .csv line by line, capture the string ID and string values into the key/value of a hash, but I'm unsure of how to actually do that, much less merge two (or more) of those into a single hash.

Any guidance/direction would be greatly appreciated. I only started learning perl last week using a lot of trial/error and the resources I've found online, and I've gotten fairly comfortable with $scalars and @arrays but hashes are unfamiliar territory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough outline for what you might want to do:

Read all three files in, and extract the information you want into vars.

```
while (<$file1>){
    chomp;
    my ($id, $word) = /"(\d+)","(.*)"/;
```

For each file, assign the first column as a hash key, and the word as the value:

```
    $english_hash{$id} = $word;
}
```

Once you have all files stored in hashes like this, you can look for overlap between the keys in different hashes:

```
    for my $id (keys %english_hash){
    print "$id\t English: $english_hash{$id}\t";
        if (exists $french_hash{$id}){
            print "French: $french_hash{$id}\n";
        }
        else {print "French: [...]\n"}  
}
```

From the English and French inputs this prints:

```
55547    English: Bonus string! French: [...]
55548    English: Please help.  French: S'il vous plaît aider.
55545    English: Hello.    French: Bonjour.
55546    English: I'm new to perl.  French: Je suis nouveau à perl.
```

Comment: For `if exists $french_hash{$id};`, would I repeat this for each language?

Comment: Yes - so that you find values (words) that share the same key (numeric ids) across all hashes...

Comment: I'm still having an issue introducing more than one language into the mix. 

I want to be able to output entries that exist in English, even if they don't exist in other languages, in which case I want to substitute an empty value ("") to keep the column structure intact. Is this possible? Removing `if exists $french_hash{$id};` results in an uninitialized value error, and I'm not sure where (or how) to define the `$french_hash{$id}` statement.

Comment: Addendum: I considered adding another `print` entry with `unless exists` instead of `if exists`, but then you run into a problem when you introduce more than 2 languages - you'd have to have entries for each possible outcome, which grows exponentially.

Comment: @nkaun - I'd just stick with a few if statements. I''ve updated the answer - which should produce the right results for English and French...

Comment: Hi, I didn't see your response. I wound up working it out from what you'd posted.

I added an uglier `unless exists` statement before each `if exists` statement that substituted the localized string for two quotation marks. From there, I simply fed the resulting .csv file back into a new hash and repeated the process for the next language. That way, the French strings get paired with the proper English strings and are treated as part of the value, retaining the info I need.

Thanks for the help!